# How should I use Cramer’s rule in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

The relationship between the two matrices is shown is `Ax=B`.

How do I find `x` using Cramer’s rule?

```
A=[521 202 -176 612;-761 41 -655 712;314 102 -234 891;612 291 209 -318]

B=[718;408;215;356]
```

Comment: do you HAVE to use cramers rule? is this an assignment?

Comment: Yes i should use Cramer’s rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) like this for your specific 4x4 case. The element at index `i` of the result `x` is given by the ratio of 2 determinants (See the wikipedia link for a full explanation) - you can create the result with the following loop

```
 x = ones(4,1);
 a_det = det(A);
 for i = 1:4
    C = A;
    C(:,i) = B;
    x(i,1) = det(C)/a_det;
 end
```

the column vector `x` should now be your result. There could be a faster way to do this but this should work. You can verify this by comparing the result with

```
x = A\B;
```

Comment: what does A\B mean in Matlab? How is it different from standard division?

Comment: @cuabanana It is the matrix divide function. It will solve a linear  system of equations be it a square or an overdetermined system. I believe that the function will use the most appropriate technique with respect to numerical stability - but that is perhaps wrong.